# Android View Flow with buttons and swipe

Tags: android, view, swipe

I have a set of images named a1 to a7 I need to swipe this images as well as i have to add a forward and backward buttons for navigation.Rigt now I am just using a circle view flow I am able to swipe. But I don't know how to add buttons. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not so much clear. Please edit your question before it gets down rate. Make your question more clear and show some of your search results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood fully. If you want to swipe left and right, you don't need buttons, that's why you swipe.
If you need every image to be in separate tabs check: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html

If you want some examples of just swiping/scrolling the images horizontally:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView

Comment: some more examples:https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/scroll_views_scrollable.js
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/image_view_file.js